# Getting the First Sunday in any Given Year in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime, mktime

I'm making a list of all the weeks in any year starting with Sunday. They year is entered and then the weeks are measured. The problem is that Sundays don't always occur on the same day, so using mktime is probably not going to work.

Obviously, every year's first Sunday isn't the same. I need to tweak the "$firstDayOfYear" variable to make it compatible with every year, not just 2020--the example I provided.

This is what I've gotten so far:

```
    $year           = $chosen_year; //entered year
    $firstDayOfYear = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 5, $year); //first Sunday of year (2020)
    $nextSunday     = strtotime('sunday', $firstDayOfYear); //Beginning of week
    $nextSaturday   = strtotime('saturday', $nextSunday); //End of week
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first sunday of january 2020'));` and replace the year with any given year

Comment: @JayBlanchard I figured this out right before you answered. However, I think certain dates are a little messed up. For instance, 2023's first Sunday is supposed to be January 1st. But it returns January 8th and completely skips the first week. Any ideas?

Comment: @EMcCrary https://3v4l.org/SIZjp ?

Comment: It works for me and @Jeto. What is your PHP version?

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.3. Do you think it's a problem if it were outdated?

Comment: @JayBlanchard https://3v4l.org/C3XuL This is my full implementation. You see that it's wrong here, too.

Comment: You forgot the `of` in `first sunday of january` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/690b4115cae2d543b094be25391d0b6e4d13592c The smallest thing will get you.

Comment: Ah, of course. My fat fingers and I. Thanks for the help!